# Suggest combobox in Outlook 2007 add-in

Tags: combobox, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I have an msoControlComboBox item in an Outlook 2007 command bar. I am able to add items to the combo box dropdown, and if the user types something in the textbox that matches the beginning of any words in the dropdown, then the combobox suggests the rest of the word, inside the text box.

I would like to do a little better than that.

1. I would like to be able to detect keypress events, and add/remove items from the dropdown list based on the characters the user has entered so far.
2. I would also like to be able to dropdown the list programatically (right now the only to drop it down appears for the user to click on the dropdown arrow).

Is there a way to accomplish these two objectives (in c#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box microsoft control that can do it.

You aren't the first person to want this however and I personally used a control found [here](http://code.google.com/p/email-autocomplete/) and found it to be a good starting point for my needs. It's aimed at finding in email addresses but it can be adapted to other needs. It uses regexp searches to find matches

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to show this in an office add-in toolbar? MsoControlType.msoControlCustom cannot be used :(